# Is it possible to update a javascript method via debugger in firefox and chrome?

Tags: javascript, security, google-chrome, firefox

Does anyone knows the steps to change javascript function via debugger in firefox or chrome? Is there any serious security concerns in it?

Comment: That's two different issues. Please open two separate questions.

Comment: 1. How to change methods 2. How to prevent changes in WebSQL DB

Comment: sure...will do it...thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps to change JS function using chrome devtools are as follow:

1. Open chrome dev tools (you can use right-click and then choose inspect element).
2. Open the 'Source' tab.
3. Choose the javascript file that contain the function you wish to change.
4. Edit the code.
5. Click on 'ctrl-s' to save it.
6. You are done. If this code is being called from an event on the page (e.g. click on a button) you will be able to see your changes without any reload.

As for security concerns, you should always validate the user input on the server side. On the client you should 'guide' the user to enter the right data but never trust it. There are many cases where someone will be able to change the data 'on the fly' (=man in the middle) so you should never trust the client.

Comment: Even if the code is changed, changes are not reflected. How do i make sure that changes are reflected on the site?

Comment: It's depend if the changes you made are going to be trigger by events/actions that aren't part of the 'onLoad'. Like in the example I gave in #6 - a click event that will trigger your changes would work.